# Error=> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem when I execute my android app in Android Studio it shows error as mention below. How can I fix this problem?

```
Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Could not create service of type AnnotationProcessorDetector using JavaGradleScopeServices.createAnnotationProcessorDetector().
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.toshiba.bluetooth_deneme"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Please add your gradle files to your question. [mcve] please

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/android-studio-3-0-gradle-build-exception-issue/24554/3

Answer (score 3):

I was running into a similar issue and it just turned out my project needed to be re-synced. Clicking the button below fixed it for me. (I can't say why that happens though.)

[image: Sync Project Button]